# The gamma and cost parameter of SVM

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

everybody, here is a weird phenomenon when I was using libSVM to make some predictions.

When I set no parameters of SVM, I will get a 99.9% performance on the testing set. While, if I set parameters '-c 10 -g 5', I will get about 33% precision on the testing set.

By the way, the SVM toolkit I am using is LibSVM.

I wonder if there is something wrong with data set. And I could not figure out which result is more convincing.

Comment: Further to Marc's answer you should use a separate validation set to choose good values for C and g. Or use grid.py (supplied with libsvm) to obtain these parameters via cross validation.

Comment: And this is highly recommended reading: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf

Comment: The LIBSVM guide is indeed a very good initial reference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just happen to have a problem for which the default values for `C` and `gamma` work well (1 and 1/num_features, respectively).

`gamma=5` is significantly larger than the default value. It is perfectly plausible for `gamma=5` to induce very poor results, when the default value is close to optimal. The combination of large `gamma` and large `C` is a perfect recipe for overfitting (e.g. high training set performance and low test set performance).

Comment: Do you mean that the default `C` and `gamma` happen to work well? I thought the too high accuracy out of place in consideration to a real-world problem. So am I supposed to check if there are any features failed?

Comment: Yes, the default `C` and `gamma` happen to be good values. You can get very high accuracy in many real world problems. Just make sure you don't evaluate the classifier on the training set. What do you mean by checking if any features failed?

Comment: Evaluating the classifier on the training set is actually a good idea (so long as you also do it on a validation set and test set!) as it can help you judge whether more training data or better features might help get a better model, but this is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: @MarcClaesen Actually, I doubt if there are features wrongly extracted, which reveals the information of label directly.