# Using SVM with opencv?

Tags: opencv

I have feature vector of size 100 .Total training samples are 500 in which there are 10 samples of each class.I want to design a separate svm classifier for each class.That is classifier of each class will be fed with 10 positive(for that class) and 490 negative instances.
My opencv code is as follows

For training:

```
Mat trainingDataMat(500, 100, CV_32FC1, trainingData);//trainingData is 2D MATRIX

Mat labelsMat(500, 1, CV_32FC1, labels);//10 positive and 490 -ve labels
CvSVMParams params;
params.svm_type = SVM::C_SVC;
params.kernel_type = SVM::RBF;
CvSVM SVM; 
SVM.train_auto(trainingDataMat, labelsMat, Mat(), Mat(), params,5);
SVM.save(name);
```

For testing

```
Mat sampleMat(1, size, CV_32FC1, testing_vector);// testing_vector is 1D vector
CvSVM SVM;
SVM.load(name);
float response = SVM.predict(sampleMat);
```

The problem is that the classifier for class outputs -1 even when I give positive testing sample from the training set and same is the case for other testing samples.

I also tried ONE_CLASS svm but it gives 0 for every testing sample.

Where am I going wrong or what svm type should I use?Please explain with code if possible.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you've missed the normalization step. SVM classifier in OpenCV uses the same as [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/), and if you read the documentation of libsvm it says you should normalize your train data in the interval [-1,1] and get scale parameters. Then use those scale parameters to scale your test data. This might be the one problem. Or it can be because of non-equivalent number of positive and negative samples. Did tried to classify your train data as a cross validation, after you have trained the SVM?

Comment: :The data is already scaled.Yes the data has non equivalent number of positive and negative samples(10 positive and 490 negatives). So will it possible to classify this data with svm? .Also can I use ONE_CLASS SVM here? .Thanks.

Comment: I don't think anyone can say that if a data can be classified with SVM or not. Data should be classifiable so that SVM can classify it. If your data is not classifiable not just SVM, no other classifiers can't classify it. SVM is just a sophisticated and easy to use classifier, only if your data is classifiable.

What kind of data are you trying to classify? And what is the reason you are not giving close number of positive and negative train samples?

Comment: :Actually I am trying to classify face data.I have a face descriptor on the basis of which I want to classify.For each person I an having 10 samples,so while training SVM(one per person) I am labeling 10 positive and all remaining as negative.So while testing for 1st,2nd person I will use SVM1,SVM2 and so on.Is non classifiable data the reason?

Comment: Ok, your data is face data but what kind of data? DCT coefficients, LBP faetures? I was trying to say that may be your descriptor was not correct for the problem, for example if you are using color histogram for face verification, it will most probably fail. Maybe you can test using only 2 users. Train your system using 10 positive and 10 negative example and test on it, if it fails, I can say that your problem is not SVM but something else.

Comment: @guneykaiym:ya got the problem ,it was the descriptor only

Comment: Like I guessed, grats :) By the way it is polite to accept the answer or upvote the answer/comment that helped you solve your problem ;)

Comment: @guneykaiym:I am new here and cannot upvote until I have 15 reputations.

Comment: @guneykayim: "SVM classifier in OpenCV uses the same as libsvm" Interesting information, thanks!

Comment: "10 positive and 490 negatives" - great you can get 98% accuracy just be classifying everything as negative. You either need equal numbers of negatives or positives or you will have to use weighting. Having only 10 positives is useless - how are you going to do cross validation to get proper values for svm_params? I recommend using the libsvm command line tools until you know what you a re doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try use linear kernel and approximately equal positives and negatives, for each class. You can ajust precision/recall by setting values of gamma and cost parameters. Take a look at:  [The gamma and cost parameter of SVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649804/the-gamma-and-cost-parameter-of-svm)